# Logging web service requests in Django

Tags: django, web-services, logging

I have created a REST web service using Django. This web service has a log file. I'd like to log all web service (http) requests in the log file. However, the web service request handling is done by Django, I only setup url-request handlers mapping and create the request handlers (views in Django nomenclature). Is there a way to log all requests in a central point, without needing to log each request in its associated request handler (view)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes Django has a built in [signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#module-django.core.signals) framework.

It allows you to register a function to be called everytime a request starts.

[This documenation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/#connecting-receiver-functions) page explains how to do it step by step

Using the decorator method:

```
from django.core.signals import request_started
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(request_started)
def my_callback(sender, **kwargs):
    # log the request here
    pass
```

> Where should this code live? You can put signal handling and
>   registration code anywhere you like. However, you’ll need to make sure
>   that the module it’s in gets imported early on so that the signal
>   handling gets registered before any signals need to be sent. This
>   makes your app’s models.py a good place to put registration of signal
>   handlers.